# Change paragraph text when bullet slider (swiper.js) is clicked not working on Elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

So I have this website that uses Elementor Builder and a slider showing some images and I'd like to change a paragraph text above the slider depending on the image.

The thing is that the bullets do not have an id assigned so I tried to do it using javascript.

I'm trying to use vanilla javascript.

Code below:

```
       var bulletFloors = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-pagination-bullet');
    
       for (var i = 0; i < bulletFloors.length; i++)
       bulletFloors[i].id = 'bulletFloors-' + i;
    
        function floort1() {
        document.getElementById('desc_apartamento').innerHTML = "Paragraph text 1.";
        }
    
        function floort2() {
        document.getElementById('desc_apartamento').innerHTML = "Paragraph text 2.";
        }
    
    function floort3() {
        document.getElementById('desc_apartamento').innerHTML = "Paragraph text 3";
    }
    
    function floort3village() {
        document.getElementById('desc_apartamento').innerHTML = "Paragraph text 4.";
    }
    
    function floort4() {
        document.getElementById('desc_apartamento').innerHTML = "Paragraph text 5.";
    }
    
    
    document.getElementById('bulletFloors-0').onclick = function() {
        floort1();
    };
    document.getElementById('bulletFloors-1').onclick = function() {
        floort2();
    };
    document.getElementById('bulletFloors-2').onclick = function() {
        floort3();
    };
    document.getElementById('bulletFloors-3').onclick = function() {
        floort3village();
    };
    document.getElementById('bulletFloors-4').onclick = function() {
        floort4();
    };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can send visual example of your slider? Maybe link to your site? Are you doing something wrong initially, why are you assigning text from js, and not through the slider options? through the admin panel?

Comment: I can't send the link because the website is in private mode. I need to place the text outside the slider. That's why I have to control it with javascript.

Comment: It doesn't matter, everything related to content should come from the admin panel. Create all 5 paragraphs on the page one after another and hide them using css and add the "Show" class to the active paragraph, you must give the ability to change the content through the admin panel, your logic is not correct

Comment: And also you shouldn't hack by clicking on bullets, you should use the api of your slider, tell me which plugin/widget do you use? Can you send a link to it? swiperjs ? Indicate in your question which slider you are using!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm using swiper.js

Comment: Please indicate this in your question, otherwise your question will be useless and get negative response, and try to rephrase your question in relation to slides and a specific slider

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress or other CMS you should always avoid unnecessary hacks, especially related to content! Do not add any content via js code!
If you are already in an environment where [jQuery is supported](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/jquery/), do not be afraid to use it.

What should you do?

- Create all your pararaphs with your builder on the page, one by one!
- Give each paragraph or rather your paragraph widget (text widget) an
  arbitrary class, for example a **"dynamic-paragraph"** and assign a unique class by index to all paragraphs, example: .p0, .p1 etc
- Hide all your paragraphs with css

```css
.dynamic-paragraph {display:none}
```

Avoid hacks such as "click on bullets" this is not an option! Because the slider can be swapped, it can have arrows for move slides, etc. Thus, you cannot provide a 100% chance that your paragraph will have dynamic text depending on the slide change! **Therefore, find out the name of the slider and use its api!**

I think you are using swiper.js, then [see this link](https://developers.elementor.com/expose-swiper-in-elementor)

You can get access to the slider:

```
const instance = jQuery('#my-id .swiper-container' );

// or

(function($) {
const instance = $('#my-id .swiper-container' );
})(jQuery);
```

**Tip**: where *#my-id .swiper-container* - selector to your slider

And then use the [api slider](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events)

```
(function($) {
const instance = $('#my-id .swiper-container' );
instance.on('slideChange', function () {
  let activeSlide = instance.activeIndex;
  $('.dynamic-paragraph.show').removeClass('show');
  $('.dynamic-paragraph.p'+activeSlide+').addClass('show');
  console.log('slide changed');
});
})(jQuery);
```

etc

Comment: it did't work. Console shows no error. I don't get it.

Comment: show me a part of html code that is rendered on the client that contains a selector